# Capturing ellipsis arguments from within an internal function

Tags: r, rlang

I'm trying to extract arguments passed to `...` from within an internal function to perform validity check. Since the only purpose of the function is to check ellipsis, I'd like the function to have no parameter and capture the ellipsis from the parent function internally.

Here's a simple example of what I'd like to do:

```r
check_dots <- function() {
  # capture ... arguments here
  if (rlang::dots_n(...) == 1L && ... == "foo") {
    stop()
  }
}

(function(...) {
  check_dots()
  "success"
})("foo", "bar")
```

I've tried using `formals(fun = rlang::caller_fn())` to extract `...` arguments without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following, using base R, does what you want:

```
check_dots = function () {
  call = match.call(definition = sys.function(-1L), call = sys.call(-1L), expand.dots = FALSE)
  if (length(call$...) == 1L && call$...[[1L]] == 'foo') stop('error')
}
```

‘rlang’ has `caller_call` as an rough equivalent of `match.call`, but it’s missing an option to prevent expanding dots, so I don’t know how to do the same as above using ‘rlang’.

Comment: Works great. Gave `caller_call` a try, it works using `dot_args <- as.list(caller_call())[-1]`. I can then test the length and value of `dot_args` in the if statement.

Comment: @Junitar your `caller_call` solution doesn’t work if the caller has other arguments besides `...`, because `as.list(caller_call())[-1L]` simply returns *all* arguments.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right!